# Convert JSON API response to pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm struggling to convert a JSON API response into a pandas Dataframe object. I've read answers to similar questions/documentation but nothing has helped. My closest attempt is below:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.xxx')
data = r.text
df = pd.read_json(data, orient='records')
```

Which returns the following format:

```
0    {'type': 'bid', 'price': 6.193e-05, ...},

1    {'type': 'bid', 'price': 6.194e-05, ...},

3    {'type': 'bid', 'price': 6.149e-05, ...} etc
```

The original format of the data is:

```
{'abc': [{'type': 'bid', 
          'price': 6.194e-05, 
          'amount': 2321.37952545, 
          'tid': 8577050, 
          'timestamp': 1498649162}, 
         {'type': 'bid', 
          'price': 6.194e-05, 
          'amount': 498.78993587,
          'tid': 8577047, 
          'timestamp': 1498649151},
          ...]}
```

I'm happy to be directed to good documentation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you need [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas import json_normalize 
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.xxx')
data = r.text

df = json_normalize(data, 'abc')
print (df)

        amount     price      tid   timestamp type
0  2321.379525  0.000062  8577050  1498649162  bid
1   498.789936  0.000062  8577047  1498649151  bid
```

For multiple keys is possible use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `list comprehension` and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d =  {'abc': [{'type': 'bid', 'price': 6.194e-05, 'amount': 2321.37952545, 'tid': 8577050, 'timestamp': 1498649162}, {'type': 'bid', 'price': 6.194e-05, 'amount': 498.78993587, 'tid': 8577047, 'timestamp': 1498649151}],
      'def': [{'type': 'bid', 'price': 6.194e-05, 'amount': 2321.37952545, 'tid': 8577050, 'timestamp': 1498649162}, {'type': 'bid', 'price': 6.194e-05, 'amount': 498.78993587, 'tid': 8577047, 'timestamp': 1498649151}]}
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in d.items()], keys=d)
print (df)
            amount     price      tid   timestamp type
abc 0  2321.379525  0.000062  8577050  1498649162  bid
    1   498.789936  0.000062  8577047  1498649151  bid
def 0  2321.379525  0.000062  8577050  1498649162  bid
    1   498.789936  0.000062  8577047  1498649151  bid
```

Comment: What is d in: df = json_normalize(d, 'abc')

Comment: d is API response to, which is r in the question posted.

Comment: I updated this to make it clearer. Thank you for the answer, jezrael, it's been helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

You could try with pandas and `StringIO` from io;
As follow:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


response = requests.get('https://api.xxx')

result = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text))
print(result)
```