# extract azure luis output to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-language-understanding

Published an app in luis service , would like to use that programmatically with python

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.runtime import LUISRuntimeClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

// Create client with SubscriptionKey and Endpoint
client = LUISRuntimeClient(
'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',             # Change "westus" to your region if necessary
CognitiveServicesCredentials("[LUIS_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY]"),  # Put your LUIS Subscription key
)

// Predict
 df['utternace'].apply(lambda x: client.prediction.resolve('XXXXXXXXXXXXX',x))
```

(XXXXXXX is  application ID)

Output is not providing the score as per documentation

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'query': 'implication the entity may not be able to monitor details effectively ', 'altered_query': None, 'top_scoring_intent': **<azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.runtime.models.intent_model_py3.IntentModel object at 0x000001FEBBC81588>**, 'intents': None, 'entities': [], 'composite_entities': None, 'sentiment_analysis': **<azure.cognitiveservices.language.luis.runtime.models.sentiment_py3.Sentiment object at 0x000001FEBBC810B8>}**
```

From the Documentation Output should be like this

Sample Output:
[image]

How can I extract LUIS result to pandas dataframe

Comment: Could you add link to mentioned documentation?

Comment: Have you had any luck in getting the result to populate the dataframe? Could you also try re-publishing? Around the time you posted this there was a small issue which required pressing the publishing button twice (both showing success) in order for the publish to take.

Comment: Just need to convert your JSON response to Dataframe same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802160/convert-json-api-response-to-pandas-dataframe