# How to convert nested json into python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert my nested json format into pandas dataframe i have tried but my data is something looking like this which is not correct

[image]

I have tried to fetch the json and save inside the innings dictionary and tried to convert into the pandas which is not working in the proper format

**innings is the dictionary which i am trying to convert into pandas dataframe but it is not converting in the proper format**

this is my json something like this

```
{
  '1164223': [
    {
      'ball_limit': '300',
      'balls': '300',
      'batted': '1',
      'batting_team_id': '2591',
      'bowling_team_id': '1832',
      'bpo': '6',
      'byes': '1',
      'event': '0',
      'event_name': None,
      'extras': '11',
      'innings_number': '1',
      'innings_numth': '1st',
      'lead': '308',
      'legbyes': '4',
      'live_current': '0',
      'live_current_name': None,
      'minutes': None,
      'noballs': '0',
      'old_penalty_or_bonus': '0',
      'over_limit': '50.0',
      'over_limit_run_rate': '6.16',
      'over_split_limit': '0.0',
      'overs': '50.0',
      'overs_docked': '0',
      'penalties': '0',
      'penalties_field_end': '0',
      'penalties_field_start': '0',
      'run_rate': '6.16',
      'runs': '308',
      'target': '0',
      'wickets': '6',
      'wides': '6'
    },
    {
      'ball_limit': '300',
      'balls': '294',
      'batted': '1',
      'batting_team_id': '1832',
      'bowling_team_id': '2591',
      'bpo': '6',
      'byes': '0',
      'event': '0',
      'event_name': None,
      'extras': '10',
      'innings_number': '2',
      'innings_numth': '1st',
      'lead': '3',
      'legbyes': '1',
      'live_current': '1',
      'live_current_name': 'current innings',
      'minutes': None,
      'noballs': '1',
      'old_penalty_or_bonus': '0',
      'over_limit': '50.0',
      'over_limit_run_rate': '6.22',
      'over_split_limit': '0.0',
      'overs': '49.0',
      'overs_docked': '0',
      'penalties': '0',
      'penalties_field_end': '0',
      'penalties_field_start': '0',
      'run_rate': '6.34',
      'runs': '311',
      'target': '309',
      'wickets': '6',
      'wides': '8'
    }
  ],
  '1165045': [
    {
      'ball_limit': '300',
      'balls': '271',
      'batted': '1',
      'batting_team_id': '1003',
      'bowling_team_id': '2989',
      'bpo': '6',
      'byes': '0',
      'event': '1',
      'event_name': 'all out',
      'extras': '10',
      'innings_number': '1',
      'innings_numth': '1st',
      'lead': '169',
      'legbyes': '4',
      'live_current': '0',
      'live_current_name': None,
      'minutes': None,
      'noballs': '1',
      'old_penalty_or_bonus': '0',
      'over_limit': '50.0',
      'over_limit_run_rate': '3.38',
      'over_split_limit': '0.0',
      'overs': '45.1',
      'overs_docked': '0',
      'penalties': '0',
      'penalties_field_end': '0',
      'penalties_field_start': '0',
      'run_rate': '3.74',
      'runs': '169',
      'target': '0',
      'wickets': '10',
      'wides': '5'
    },
    {
      'ball_limit': '300',
      'balls': '239',
      'batted': '1',
      'batting_team_id': '2989',
      'bowling_team_id': '1003',
      'bpo': '6',
      'byes': '0',
      'event': '3',
      'event_name': 'target reached',
      'extras': '12',
      'innings_number': '2',
      'innings_numth': '1st',
      'lead': '1',
      'legbyes': '6',
      'live_current': '1',
      'live_current_name': 'current innings',
      'minutes': None,
      'noballs': '0',
      'old_penalty_or_bonus': '0',
      'over_limit': '50.0',
      'over_limit_run_rate': '3.40',
      'over_split_limit': '0.0',
      'overs': '39.5',
      'overs_docked': '0',
      'penalties': '0',
      'penalties_field_end': '0',
      'penalties_field_start': '0',
      'run_rate': '4.26',
      'runs': '170',
      'target': '170',
      'wickets': '3',
      'wides': '6'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON API response to Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802160/convert-json-api-response-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `dictionary comprehension`:

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in j.items()})
print (df)
          ball_limit balls batted batting_team_id bowling_team_id bpo byes  \
1164223 0        300   300      1            2591            1832   6    1   
        1        300   294      1            1832            2591   6    0   
1165045 0        300   271      1            1003            2989   6    0   
        1        300   239      1            2989            1003   6    0   

          event      event_name extras  ...  overs overs_docked penalties  \
1164223 0     0            None     11  ...   50.0            0         0   
        1     0            None     10  ...   49.0            0         0   
1165045 0     1         all out     10  ...   45.1            0         0   
        1     3  target reached     12  ...   39.5            0         0   

          penalties_field_end penalties_field_start run_rate runs target  \
1164223 0                   0                     0     6.16  308      0   
        1                   0                     0     6.34  311    309   
1165045 0                   0                     0     3.74  169      0   
        1                   0                     0     4.26  170    170   

          wickets wides  
1164223 0       6     6  
        1       6     8  
1165045 0      10     5  
        1       3     6  

[4 rows x 32 columns]
```

Another solution is loop in `dict comprehension` and [add key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34757497) of outer dicts for list of dicts, last pass to `DataFrame` contructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(x, **{'_id':k}) for k, v in j.items() for x in v])
print (df)
       _id ball_limit balls batted batting_team_id bowling_team_id bpo byes  \
0  1164223        300   300      1            2591            1832   6    1   
1  1164223        300   294      1            1832            2591   6    0   
2  1165045        300   271      1            1003            2989   6    0   
3  1165045        300   239      1            2989            1003   6    0   

  event      event_name  ...  overs overs_docked penalties  \
0     0            None  ...   50.0            0         0   
1     0            None  ...   49.0            0         0   
2     1         all out  ...   45.1            0         0   
3     3  target reached  ...   39.5            0         0   

  penalties_field_end penalties_field_start run_rate runs target wickets wides  
0                   0                     0     6.16  308      0       6     6  
1                   0                     0     6.34  311    309       6     8  
2                   0                     0     3.74  169      0      10     5  
3                   0                     0     4.26  170    170       3     6  

[4 rows x 33 columns]
```