# Dataframe from API to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv

I'm at python and try to export datas from an API to a csv

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article"
#r = requests.get('https://api.bexio.com/2.0/article')
headers = {
'Accept': "application/json",
'Content-Type': "application/json",
'Authorization': "Bearer xxx}
```

That works fine.

```
  [{"id":34,"user_id":1,"article_type_id":1,"contact_id":null,"deliverer_code":"","deliverer_name":"","deliverer_description":"","intern_code":"TEXLINE-SOLD","intern_name":"TEXLINE Sold out","intern_description":"","purchase_price":"0.900000","sale_price":"2.450000","purchase_total":null,"sale_total":null,"currency_id":1,"tax_income_id":16,"tax_id":16,"tax_expense_id":22,"unit_id":1,"is_stock":true,"stock_id":null,"stock_place_id":null,"stock_nr":0,"stock_min_nr":0,"stock_reserved_nr":0,"stock_available_nr":0,"stock_picked_nr":0,"stock_disposed_nr":0,"stock_ordered_nr":0,"width":null,"height":null,"weight":null,"volume":null,"html_text":null,"remarks":"
```

the problem here is, i want to export this data to csv where is then nicely listed in a table. I tried with

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
dic = response.json()
df = pandas.DataFrame(dic)
df.to_csv('detections.csv', index=False, sep="\t")
```

or with pandas as pd. But that dosen't work.

Comment: This might help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802160/convert-json-api-response-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Try with `read_json` if you have your JSON as a string:

```
df = pd.read_json(json_string)
```

Or, alternatively, converting the API response to python list with `.json()` and directly creating a `DataFrame` from that list:

```
r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
```

---

If the response is not a list (`[{..}, .., {..}]`), but a single object (`{..}`):

```
r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json(), index=[0])
```

Comment: Thank u for the response. I tried that and that's the response `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 15, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
  File "/home/ariahi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 468, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: OK, so most likely what you're getting as a response is a single object, not a list. Try `df = pd.DataFrame(r.json(), index=[0])`

Comment: Thanks! I got no error but at the same time i got no output. `ari@localhost:~/fastgeschaft$ python3 final.py
ari@localhost:~/fastgeschaft$`

Comment: If you use the code that you posted above, then you're writing the dataframe to the `detections.csv` file (`df.to_csv(...` line), and you don't have any console output there

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is how it worked :). The last problem I have is that the export to CSV is chaotic. There are 20 entries in one Excel column. I want to have it so that "max_stock" is shown as "Stockmax" in the header and below that the number "40" and a few other entries the same. How can I solve this?