# creating pandas df from disctionary in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data coming from API like below:

```
> {'Message': {'Success': True, 'ErrorMessage': ''},
> 'StoresAttributes': [{'StoreCode': '1004',
> 'Categories': [{'Code': 'Lctn',
> 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Long', 'Value': '16.99390523395146'}},
> {'Code': 'Lctn',
> 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Lat', 'Value': '52.56718450856377'}},
> {'Code': 'Offr', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Bake', 'Value': 'True'}},
> {'Code': 'Pay', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'SCO', 'Value': 'True'}}]},
> {'StoreCode': '1005',
> 'Categories': [{'Code': 'Lctn',
> 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Long', 'Value': '14.2339250'}},
> {'Code': 'Lctn', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Lat', 'Value': '53.8996090'}},
> {'Code': 'Offr', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Bake', 'Value': 'True'}},
> {'Code': 'Pay', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'SCO', 'Value': 'True'}},
> {'Code': 'Offr', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Bchi', 'Value': 'True'}}]},
```

And I want to make data frame from it. I have tried with loop or pd.DataFrame() function but it didn't work properly.

What I want to achieve is df with subsequent columns:

StoreCode: 1004,
Long: 16,99,
Lat: 52,56,
Bake: True.

Can please anyone help?

Below screen with my result from json_normalize

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvLhP.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON API response to pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802160/convert-json-api-response-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_normalize` then `pivot`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Message': {'Success': True, 'ErrorMessage': ''}, 'StoresAttributes': [{'StoreCode': '1004', 'Categories': [{'Code': 'Lctn', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Long', 'Value': '16.99390523395146'}}, {'Code': 'Lctn', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Lat', 'Value': '52.56718450856377'}}, {'Code': 'Offr', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Bake', 'Value': 'True'}}, {'Code': 'Pay', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'SCO', 'Value': 'True'}}]}, {'StoreCode': '1005', 'Categories': [{'Code': 'Lctn', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Long', 'Value': '14.2339250'}}, {'Code': 'Lctn', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Lat', 'Value': '53.8996090'}}, {'Code': 'Offr', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Bake', 'Value': 'True'}}, {'Code': 'Pay', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'SCO', 'Value': 'True'}}, {'Code': 'Offr', 'Attribute': {'Code': 'Bchi', 'Value': 'True'}}]}]}
    
df = pd.json_normalize(data['StoresAttributes'], meta='StoreCode', record_path='Categories')
df.pivot(columns='Attribute.Code', values='Attribute.Value', index='StoreCode')
```

Output:

```
Attribute.Code  Bake  Bchi                Lat               Long   SCO
StoreCode
1004            True   NaN  52.56718450856377  16.99390523395146  True
1005            True  True         53.8996090         14.2339250  True
```

Comment: It worked only on your example, I think you chave changes sth in it. Key Error: 'Categories'

Comment: I simply closed the opened list and dict of your example, adding `]` and `}` at the end (otherwise it is not a valid dictionary). Please edit your question to share the data causing problem.

Comment: I shared screen in main question

Comment: A screenshot doesn't help reproducing the problem. Besides you set `record_path='Attribute'` instead of `record_path='Categories'`

Comment: take a look now, please.

Comment: Like I said, I can't reproduce your error based on screenshots. One of the elements in `data['StoresAttributes']` probably misses the 'Categories' Key... Please provide a *valid* python object causing the problem. Also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! Could you just please tell me, if I want to check if all item in loop has 'Categories' key and after that add to my df. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `[x for x in data['StoresAttributes'] if 'Categories' in x]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_normalize()` function like this:

```py
data = [
     {"id": 1, "name": {"first": "Coleen", "last": "Volk"}},
     {"name": {"given": "Mark", "family": "Regner"}},
     {"id": 2, "name": "Faye Raker"},
 ]

pd.json_normalize(data)
```

**Output:**

```bash
    id name.first name.last name.given name.family        name
0  1.0     Coleen      Volk        NaN         NaN         NaN
1  NaN        NaN       NaN       Mark      Regner         NaN
2  2.0        NaN       NaN        NaN         NaN  Faye Raker
```

You can refer to the below link to know more about the `json_normalize()` function.

[**CLICK HERE**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)