# Converting a JSON Response into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I have this code that returns a json response.

```
import requests

url = "https://usda.library.cornell.edu/api/v1/publication/findAll"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE0NDc1fQ.YpppSpjBnGfHv8DBEiWCrmv-KgtF3MLzniHF89hW9L8'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I am trying to use json_normalize as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44802232/4399016) to get a pandas data frame.

```
data = response.text

df = json_normalize(data)
print (df)
```

Getting NotImplementedError:

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `response.json()`, not `response.text` in `pd.json_normalize`:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://usda.library.cornell.edu/api/v1/publication/findAll"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE0NDc1fQ.YpppSpjBnGfHv8DBEiWCrmv-KgtF3MLzniHF89hW9L8'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

df = pd.json_normalize(response.json())
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             id                                                                 agency                                                                                                                         title                                                          contact_organization                    contact_email                                                                                                                                                                keywords        frequency      status subscribable           resource_type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              subject                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          description                                                                                               identifier agency_acronym                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              upcoming_releases division_acronym                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           related_publication
0     df65v784d                                         [Foreign Agricultural Service]                                                                                            [Tobacco: World Markets and Trade]                                                [Foreign Agricultural Service]             [Press@fas.usda.gov]                                                                                                      [cigarettes, burley tobacco, tobacco, flue-cured tobacco, tariffs]        [Monthly]  [Inactive]           No                [Report]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [Crops and Crop Products:Tobacco]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [This monthly report includes data on annual and monthly U.S. and global trade, production, and consumption of manufactured and unmanufactured tobacco on a commodity basis and a country by country basis.\n]                                                                                                [Tobacco]          [FAS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NaN              NaN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NaN
1     5x21tf405                                         [Foreign Agricultural Service]                                                                                           [Organics: World Markets and Trade]                                                [Foreign Agricultural Service]             [Press@fas.usda.gov]                                                                                                                              [organic foods, imports, exports, organic]  [Not Specified]    [Active]           No                [Report]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       [Animals and Animal Products:Specialty Animals and Animal Products, Crops and Crop Products:Specialty Crops and Crop Products]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [This report includes data on U.S. trade on a country by country basis and on a commodity basis in labeled organic foods.  Also included are analysis of developments affecting trade in organics.\n]                                                                                               [organics]          [FAS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NaN              NaN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NaN
2     k930bx013                             [National Agricultural Statistics Service]                                                                                                                [Alfalfa Seed]                                    [National Agricultural Statistics Service]             [nass@nass.usda.gov]                                                                                                                                  [alfalfa, yields, seedling production]       [Annually]  [Inactive]           No                [Report]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [Crops and Crop Products:Grains and Oilseeds]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        [This publication reported on the alfalfa seed crop, including area harvested, yield and production, as well as carryover and supply.       ]                                                                                               [AlfaSeed]         [NASS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NaN              NaN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           NaN

...
```